# Position component relative to its child

Tags: reactjs, css-position

I have in React a tooltip component that is wrapping a button component.

How can I position the tooltip relative to the button position?

```
<div class="tooltip">
  <div class="button"></div>
</div>
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/tooltip-r75g2?file=/index.html) is a codesandbox you can play with.

Comment: you can reverse the order so that the `tooltip` view is a child of `button` view, and then you can position it relative to its parent

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that with the way your markup is structured. I would suggest you making a div that wraps both the elements.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="button"></div>
  <div class="tooltip"></div>
</div>
```

You would then apply position relative to the wrapper element. Then you can use position absolute on the tooltip to position it however you want it according to the wrapping div.